# SQLite query result less than 1mb

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to make the result of query length less than 1 MB in SQLite database to keep on performance?

```
SELECT this
FROM THERE
WHERE something < 1MB
```

Comment: What is `something`? What values can it have?

Comment: it will have data as stock information but want the result of query be less than 1 MB and total result come from more than one query if there is more than 1 MB data to keep on performance

Comment: 1 MB is not much data. If you worry about performance SQLite might not  be the right tool for the job. Take a look at http://sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: its for mobile application so query should be less than 1MB

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has a function [`length(X)`](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html). With it you could do this:

```
SELECT this
  FROM there
 WHERE length(something) < (1024 * 1024);
```

**Edit:** If you want the *total* result of your query to be smaller than a specific size (measured in what: number of characters?), you will have to `LIMIT` your query.

```
SELECT this
  FROM there
 LIMIT 100;
```

Of course, `100` is just some random number I picked for the example. You'll have to measure  your queries to get a limit appropriate for your performance requirenments.

**Edit2:** `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` make a nice couple:

```
SELECT this
  FROM there
OFFSET 100
 LIMIT 100;
```

This will select the "next" 100 records from your table using standard sorting.

Details about `SELECT` in SQLite: http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: and if i have more than 1 MB data in the database file how to divide  them on more then one query with the size of 1 MB?